# Multiple greatcircle plots with python basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, great-circle

Having a tough time troubleshooting this issue:

**Plotting multiple greatcircle paths from array**

error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "example.py", line 41, in
>   
>       eq_map.drawgreatcircle(y,x,y2,x2,linewidth=6,color='b')   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py",
>   line 2893, in drawgreatcircle
>       npoints = int((dist+0.5*1000.*del_s)/(1000.*del_s)) TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list

---

Python code:

```
import csv

# Open the data file.
filename = 'sample.csv'

# Create empty lists for the latitudes and longitudes.
lats, lons = [], []
lats2, lons2 = [], []

# Read through the entire file, skip the first line,
#  and pull out just the lats and lons.
with open(filename) as f:
    # Create a csv reader object.
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # Ignore the header row.
    next(reader)

    # Store the latitudes and longitudes in the appropriate lists.
    for row in reader:
        lats.append(float(row[1]))
        lons.append(float(row[2]))
        lats2.append(float(row[4]))
        lons2.append(float(row[5]))        

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

eq_map = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-80,urcrnrlat=80,llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')

eq_map.drawcoastlines()
eq_map.drawcountries()
eq_map.fillcontinents(color = 'gray')
eq_map.drawmapboundary()
eq_map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30))
eq_map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 30))

x,y = eq_map(lons, lats)
x2,y2 = eq_map(lons2,lats2)
eq_map.drawgreatcircle(y,x,y2,x2,linewidth=6,color='b')

plt.show()
```

---

Sample.csv

```
Origin,origLat,origLon,Dest,destLat,destLon
"jfk",40.641311,-73.778139,"lax",33.941589,-118.40853
"teb",40.849023,-74.062953,"mia",34.730283,136.508588
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lons and lats are currently list. You need to iterate through to get the coordinates.

```
print(type(lons))
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
for x, y, x2, y2 in zip(lats[0::1], lons[0::1], lats2[0::1], lons2[0::1]):
    eq_map.drawgreatcircle(x, y, x2, y2, linewidth=2, color='b')
```

Unless you want to create plots as well you don't need

```
x,y = eq_map(lons, lats)
x2,y2 = eq_map(lons2,lats2)
```

With plots

```
for lats, lons, lats2, lons2 in zip(lats[0::1], lons[0::1], lats2[0::1], lons2[0::1]):
    x,y = eq_map(lons, lats)
    x2,y2 = eq_map(lons2,lats2)
    eq_map.plot(x, y, marker='.', color='r', markersize=10)
    eq_map.plot(x2, y2, marker='.', color='r', markersize=10)
    eq_map.drawgreatcircle(lons, lats, lons2, lats2, linewidth=2, color='b')
```